# Puzzled with InputField

Tags: interactive

What is wrong with the following code?

```
  Panel[DynamicModule[{a = RandomInteger[100], b = RandomInteger[100],
   f = a + b}, 
  Column[{InputField[{Dynamic[a], Dynamic[b]}], Dynamic[f]}]]]
```

Once executed the values in the panel cannot be changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with lists:

```
Panel[
 DynamicModule[{a = {RandomInteger[100], RandomInteger[100]}},
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[a]], Dynamic[Total@a]}]]]
```

or

```
DynamicModule[{b = {RandomInteger[100], RandomInteger[100]}},
 Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[b]], Dynamic[Total@b]}]]]
```